# Selenium-VBA: Get Total No of Options in a DropDown

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to get the Total Number of Options in a Dropdown through Selenium VBA and My Code looks like this:

```
ABC = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='select_pager']").Size
```

The HTML Code of the Dropdown looks like this:

```
<select id="select_pager" name="select_pager" class="dataSelect" onchange="document.ecform.goto.value=this.selectedIndex+1;movePage(0)">
                <option value="1">1</option></select>
```

Through this, I'm trying to get the No Of Options Available, and the basis on that, I would be taking a set of other actions in the browser.

Tried researching but couldn't succeed.

Comment: @RaymondWu - Have modified the Question with the HTML Code.

Comment: I don't have Selenium but based on the documentation in github - Try `driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='select_pager']").AsSelect.Options.Count`. If it doesn't work then hope someone familiar with Selenium can help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cast the element returned by `FindElementByXPath` to a `Select` element using [AsSelect](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/blob/v2.0.9.0/Selenium/ComInterfaces/_WebElement.cs#:%7E:text=%5BDispId(8300)%2C%20Description,SelectElement%20AsSelect()%3B)
then get the list of options using [Options](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/blob/v2.0.9.0/Selenium/ComInterfaces/_SelectElement.cs#:%7E:text=%5BDispId(404)%2C%20Description,WebElements%20Options%20%7B%20get%3B%20%7D) property and finally, get the number of options using [Count](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/blob/v2.0.9.0/Selenium/ComInterfaces/_List.cs#:%7E:text=%5BDispId(118)%2C%20Description,int%20Count%20%7B%20get%3B%20%7D) property.

```
ABC = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='select_pager']").AsSelect.Options.Count
```